# In .htaccess the url length increases as I browse

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

My .htaccess file contains the following code. When I am navigating through the following links the url changes but instead of completely getting substituted it gets appended to the previous page ur for eg. if my url says home and then i click on a link that takes me to donordashboard.php the url changes to home/dashboard/donar after this if i  click on another link that takes me to donor_profile.php  the url changes to home/dashboard/profileedit/donor . This way the length keeps on increasing. please help .

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule home home.php
RewriteRule add/blood_bank add_blood_bank.php
RewriteRule add/blood/donar add_as_a_blood_donar.php

RewriteRule dashboard/donor donordashboard.php
RewriteRule profileedit/donor donor_profile.php
RewriteRule add/last/donated/blood add_last_donated_blood.php
RewriteRule change/pwd/donor blood_change_pwd.php
RewriteRule logout common/logout.php

RewriteRule login_bd bdlogin.php
RewriteRule blood_donor_login blood_donor_login.php
```

Comment: Can you tell where it redirects from and to?

Answer (score 0):

This line here perhaps keeps on redirecting, right?

```
RewriteRule logout common/logout.php
```

You should put absolute urls instead

```
RewriteRule /logout /common/logout.php
```

Can you try try adding [R=301,L]

```
RewriteRule /logout /common/logout.php [R=301,L]
```

--

and also add **full absolute urls**, so your code would be:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule /home /home.php
RewriteRule /add/blood_bank /add_blood_bank.php
RewriteRule /add/blood/donar /add_as_a_blood_donar.php

RewriteRule /dashboard/donor /donordashboard.php
RewriteRule /profileedit/donor /donor_profile.php
RewriteRule /add/last/donated/blood /add_last_donated_blood.php
RewriteRule /change/pwd/donor /blood_change_pwd.php
RewriteRule /logout /common/logout.php

RewriteRule /login_bd /bdlogin.php
RewriteRule /blood_donor_login /blood_donor_login.php
```

Comment: it does not redirect it navigates to the correct page but the url gets appended to the url of previous page

Comment: it depends where you are putting php files, are they in homeroot / or in a subdirectory?

Comment: You also need to reflect on the 2nd url path

Comment: could you please exaplain a bit more i dint get the "2nd url path" ??

Comment: RewriteRule /blood_donor_login /blood_donor_login.php
, it means,
RewriteRule 1st_URL  2nd_URL

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /facebook_login/
```

Try adding `RewriteBase` if files are in root just add / or the folder path

Comment: have you changed the `RewriteBase` to your requirement ?

Comment: I think don't use RewriteBase unless its really necessary, all subfolders can be affected and use this htaccess